# How to get view from backpack button method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a laravel backpack app. I add in `setupListOperation`:

```php
addButtonFromView('line', 'getPage', 'backpack-pages::preview-page', 'beginning');
```

Set viewspace `backpack-pages`, and get error

> Button view and fallbacks do not exist for getPage button.

Why it doesn't work viewspace in view path?

Comment: this is the method:
`$this->crud->addButtonFromView($stack, $name, $view, $position);`, just check the  `$view` parameter is set to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Backpack should pick up the blade file no problem, if the `backpack-pages::preview-page` view actually exists and that namespace is properly registered.

So please make sure that view exists. To find out if that view exists, you can do `dd(View::exists('backpack-pages::preview-page')` in a Controller or in a `php artisan tinker` session.